# Can the phrase 'found with arms' be used as a qualifier?

Tags: qualifiers

I'm in a bit of confusion of what is the grammatical relation of the bold phrase containing in below sentence:

> According to the proclamation all men **found with arms** will be shot

If it's being qualified the word *'men'* here, I've no idea how *'men'* is being described/qualified by the phrase *'found with arms'*. All I can think of the relative clause, if it can be used as relative clause:

> According to the proclamation all men **who are found with arms** will be shot

Anyone can explain me how this phrase is related to this sentence? All the answers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*According to the proclamation all men **found with arms** will be shot*

The expression in bold is a past-participial clause modifying "men".

Past-participial (and gerund-participial) clauses are semantically similar to relative clauses: compare: *all men **who are found with arms** will be shot*.  But they are not analysed as relative clauses since there is no possibility of inserting a relative pronoun (cf. the ungrammatical * *men who found with arms*).